# Include local file dependencies with htmltools::html_print

Tags: r

I'm trying to create an html file with JS Code with htmltools. That works without problems. When writing the file I also add `html_print(html)` at the end to get a preview of the d3 graph I'm creating. But in the preview it doesn't know the data.csv file saved in the folder before (which makes sense, from where should it know). Is there a possibility to "upload" files to the localhost that they can be accessed from the html/js code? (I know that I could upload it to an TFP Server and include the URL, however I would prefere that it works without an external server the user needs but just everything within the localhost).

```
library(htmltools)

output_file = function(html, folder = "d3plot", file = "d3plot.html", lang = "en"){
  file = paste0(folder, "/", file)
  htmltools::save_html(html, file = file, lang = lang)
  fileContent = readr::read_file(file)
  fileContent = gsub("<html>\n", "", fileContent)
  fileContent = gsub("</html>\n</html>", "</html>", fileContent)
  readr::write_file(fileContent, file)
  html_print(html) # how to "upload" additional files like data.csv to R Studio Viewer Localhost
}

# HTML <head>
  html_doc = withTags(
        head(
          title(docTitle),
          meta(name="viewport",
               content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"),
          script(src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"),
          style(add_style(rd3obj))
        )
  )
  # HTML <body>
  body = withTags(
    body(svg(),script(HTML(paste(
      'let plot = d3.select("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height", 400).html("");',
      'd3.csv("data.csv").then(function(data){ console.log(data); });\n'
    sep = "\n"))
      
    ))
  )
  
  # add <head> and <body>
  final = tagSetChildren(tags$html(), html_doc, body)

  output_file(final)
```

Comment: You can include data using JSON, but it seems like you'd be better off using R Markdown to produce your file.  It will automatically include whatever data the D3 display needs.

Comment: For example, see http://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/ .

Comment: I think using R Markdown would make everything more complex. The goal is to write a package which produces d3 plots in a ggplot alike setup. The files which get generated all work when I start Xampp and save them there or upload it on a server. It just would be nice if one could already see the result in the viewer of R Studio to check if the autoput is the desired. I know that I could include the data directly as json but I think thats not very elegant for large files. So is there a way to send files to the viewer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably avoid writing the HTML yourself, and rely on a package that wraps the D3 library as an `htmlwidget`.  For example, from the help page for `networkD3::forceNetwork`, this displays a network in the RStudio viewer:

```r
library(networkD3)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)
# Create graph
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
             Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.4, zoom = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

One of the choices authors who write htmlwidgets make is whether to display in the viewer or in a  "zoomed" window.  The authors of `networkD3` chose to put `forceNetwork` results in the regular viewer, but `chordNetwork` results get automatically zoomed.  I don't know if you can override that choice (the `zoom` argument deals with something different).

Comment: Is there a generell d3 htmlwidget package? I just found some for specific plots like network plots. And do those widgets include csv/json files in the viewer?

Comment: I don't know the d3 library at all, so I can't answer that.  But if not, my suggestion would be to write one.  That way you write the code once and it's easy for you and others to use.  Writing an htmlwidgets package is similar work to writing code to use the library directly.